# Python Pandas If value in column B = equals [X, Y, Z] replace column A with "T"

Tags: python, pandas, comparison, multiple-columns

Say I have this array:

```
A, B
1, G
2, X
3, F
4, Z
5, I
```

If column B equals [X, Y or Z] replace column A with value "T"

I've found how to change values within the same column but not across, any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'B': ['G', 'X', 'F', 'Z', 'I']
     })
df.ix[df.B.isin(['X','Y','Z']), 'A'] = 'T'
print df
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  1  G
1  T  X
2  3  F
3  T  Z
4  5  I
```

Remember to use `ix` or `loc` to avoid setting values on a copied slice.

Answer (score 5):

Use `isin` and `loc` to set the value:

```
In [138]:

df.loc[df.B.isin(['X','Y','Z']),'A']='T'
df
Out[138]:
   A  B
0  1  G
1  T  X
2  3  F
3  T  Z
4  5  I
```

You can also use `np.where`:

```
In [140]:

df['A'] = np.where(df.B.isin(['X','Y','Z']),'T', df['A'])
df
Out[140]:
   A  B
0  1  G
1  T  X
2  3  F
3  T  Z
4  5  I
```

Comment: I think your using iPython. Do you happen to know the timeit differences between these?

Comment: @user765015 using loc on this toy example took 915 us, using where took 615us, so in this case where is 30% faster

Comment: @user765015 for a 50,000 row df loc is slightly faster 9.27ms vs 11.2 ms